# faulty url in @DataSourceDefinition

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, payara, payara-micro

### Issue

The `@DataSourceDefinition` provides the `url` property, but it will be ignored. If the the url is set to `jdbc:postgres://database:5432/demo`, a connection to `localhost:5432` will be established. The same settings work great by setting them as `serverName`, `portNumber` and `databaseName` directly.

### Demo

A small demo project to illustrate this behaviour can be found at https://github.com/ThomasPr/DataSourceDefinition

### Details

#### working example ✅

The properties `serverName`, `portNumber` and `databaseName` are set individually. A connection to postgres at `database:5432` will be established successfully.

```java
@DataSourceDefinition(
    name = "java:global/jdbc/DemoDataSource",
    className = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource",
    serverName = "database",  // set the property
    portNumber = 5432,        // set the property
    databaseName = "demo",    // set the property
    user = "demo",
    password = "demo")
```

#### failing example ❌

The same settings from the working example will be used again, but this time, only the `url` property will be set. The result is a connection attempt to `localhost:5432` instead of `database:5432`

```java
@DataSourceDefinition(
    name = "java:global/jdbc/DemoDataSource",
    className = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource",
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/demo",  // only use url, but no serverName, portNumber or databaseName
    user = "demo",
    password = "demo")
```

#### strange example

The same url-setting is used like in the failing example. But the `serverName`, `portNumber` and `databaseName` are set to empty values. Very strange: This time a connection to `database:5432` will be established successfully. The only difference to the failing example are the mentioned three empty values.

```java
@DataSourceDefinition(
    name = "java:global/jdbc/DemoDataSource",
    className = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource",
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/demo",  // use the url to configure connection properties
    user = "demo",
    password = "demo",
    serverName = "",    // set it to an empty value
    portNumber = -1,    // set it to an empty value
    databaseName = "")  // set it to an empty value
```

### Exception

During startup of Payara, the following Exception will occur in the failing case:

```
microservice_1  | [2019-12-13T14:29:00.071+0000] [] [SEVERE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/tmp/payaramicro-rt7729847129244438567tmp/applications/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/_demo.ejb] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1576247340071] [levelValue: 1000] [[
microservice_1  |
microservice_1  | Local Exception Stack:
microservice_1  | Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.payara-p2): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
microservice_1  | Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
microservice_1  | Error Code: 0
microservice_1  |   at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:318)
microservice_1  |   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:150)
microservice_1  |   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:172)
microservice_1  |   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:233)
microservice_1  |   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:815)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround with the empty parameters, saved my day. In my team we inject all values from outside, but were never able to do so for the port, because a string will be injected where int is expected. We went around that by assembling the "url" parameter instead, but then had to face the localhost issue.

Comment: The guys from Payara are already working on it: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4385

Comment: The same issue happens to me on the datasource I defined in the web.xml. After a couple of restarts it actually works.